# Can the transporter remove alcohol from a body?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter, biology, star-trek-picard

As seen in *Picard* S3, the transporter can alter a subject's DNA on "reconstruction". So if I get drunk, can the transporter remove all the alcohol from my body?

Comment: Between all the series (including Animated) and the various non-canonical Pocket Books novels, we've seen the transporter used as either a _deus ex machina_ or a Plot Device so often that there's no clear answer to any question about what it can do...

Comment: Memory Alpha (warning: fan content) claims the [Biofilters](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Biofilter) can perform all kinds of cleaning functions to incoming parties.

Comment: Forget removing, can it add alcohol to a body? That would save so much time when beaming over to a party.

Comment: If it can, it doesn't seem to do so regularly. In Strange New Worlds, we see Spock a few times returning from "Bloodwine Diplomacy", still dealing with the effects of alcohol in his blood.

Answer (score -2):

In Star Trek VI - The Undiscovered Country, Captain Kirk and Dr. Leonard McCoy are on trial. It is suggested that he may have still been intoxicated after a transport.

> KIRK: I'm going aboard. Spock, you have the conn.
>
> SPOCK: I am responsible for involving you in this. I will go.
>
> KIRK: No, I'll go. You'll be responsible for getting me out of this. We'll not be the instigators of a full-scale war on the eve of universal peace.
>
> McCOY: I'm going too. They may need a doctor.

> CHANG (on viewscreen): Ah. You know. I believe that you consumed a rather generous amount of Romulan ale in the officers' mess on the night of question. Am I right, Doctor?
>
> COLONEL WORF (on viewscreen): Objection!
>
> KLINGON JUDGE (on viewscreen): Sustained.
>
> McCOY (on viewscreen): We all did. All of us. That doesn't mean...

Edit: Transcript from http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie6.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether the transporter has that capability. At best it speaks to the suggestion that it does so automatically

Comment: @Valorum True, also transporter technology may have advanced by the time of the Picard tv series. I just remembered this scene.

Comment: Picard is such a total mess (re: canon) that it might as well be a different timeline

Comment: Spock staggers onto the bridge after diplomacy involving bloodwine in the episode that came out yesterday. He was also hungover after a similar situation earlier in the current season, so the related question of “does it happen automatically” is answered there.